# items scroll over toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new in android development and i'm trying to create scrolling layout with items on its collapsingtoolbarlayout.I have a following layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<include layout="@layout/content_profile" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvUserProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/vUserProfileRoot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="64dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clipChildren="false">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/empty_profile"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/vUserDetails"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="John Smith"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="\@jsmith"
                        android:textColor="#bbbbbb"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Mobile development passionate."
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:elevation="8dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

When i scroll,items cross over toolbar and then are hide.But i want that they scroll under toolbar.Any ideas?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView not supported on this .so that its need to use support NestedScrollView . You should test it and let me know its works or not.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/vUserProfileRoot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="64dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clipChildren="false">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/empty_profile"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/vUserDetails"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="John Smith"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="\@jsmith"
                        android:textColor="#bbbbbb"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Mobile development passionate."
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:elevation="8dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Was that helpful?